# One big background image or multiple small images?

Tags: css, html

As a web developer, I have to cut a layout similar to this (example website by [Ruben Bristian](http://themes.rubenbristian.com/hexagon/)):

[image: Hexagon by Ruben Bristian]

Should I bother with cutting multiple small images like a logo:

[image: logo]

a label:

[image: label]

and so on? Or should I just make one big background image with all elements like this:

[image: background]

and make a positioned `<a href>` with `display: block;` for a linked logo?

A single image has smaller size than multiple elements altogether. What are the other pros and cons?

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer as correct if it helped you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use separate images.

Here are a few reasons why:

**Maintenance**:
It's going to be much easier to maintain in the future, if/when there comes a point when you want to build on what you already have. Furthermore (and subjectively),  the background image is not critical to the design. It wouldn't look broken if parts of the background were clipped. It would look broken however, if the logo were distorted.

Bear in mind also that newer, sharper displays are being developed. It's much easier to display the standard resolution background (it's already blurry, so clarity is not essential), and maintain two versions of the logo. One for standard displays, one for HD.

**Semantics:** What if the user has images disabled? Sure, it's unlikely, but what about **Google**? You should have some proper markup with real content. Your site needs real textual content in order for Google's crawlers to gather information about it. Use CSS image-replacement techniques to build the interface.

**Another note on HD displays:**
It's convention to serve larger images to HD (retina) displays, and use CSS to downsize them, effectively increasing their dots-per-inch. If you use just one image, the user will have to download a *considerably large* image. More bandwidth used by you, and slower experience for your users.

Furthermore, the text will look *horrible* on HD displays. It makes much more sense to allow the browser to render razor-sharp text to the user.

**Accessibility:** For a start, screen readers won't have a clue what your site is about. That might not be so relevant in this case, but it's best practice to build and accessible website. If you want to include some smaller text on the site, some users may be unable to read it. Normally they would increase the font-size, but if you use images, they're powerless.

---

I may have over-dramatised this answer, but the advice is well-intentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I would honestly try a little bit of a different approach. The "photo" part of the image would be one image, the logo another, and maybe the double bar on either side of the heading another (but might not be necessary.

I would use the photo part as a bg image on a div, and within code the rest.

I wouldn't make the text part of the image at all. Try using a service like [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts) to get a good font.

The approach will save you lots of maintenance time, and also help with performance.

Answer (score 0):

PROS:

- Total bytes loaded is lower.
- You do not have to worry about how little images are put together to become the total image.

Answer (score 0):

if you just use 1 image you will find that it will be much easier to maintain the fluidity of the layout. You will not have padding/alignment issues, rendering issues, etc. Realistically the load time should be the same either way, maybe a tad longer for multiple images as the browser would have to render more css, but i imagine it would not be very noticable. In the end it really comes down to what is better for the job. I pretty biased towards 1 clean image :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to think about how you are going to use each element individually, and how they are going to change in the future.

You might want to change the logo, animate it, or want to re-use it elsewhere. The background image might change, or become multiple images in some sort of transitional gallery.

If this its never going to change (unlikely), then, yes, flatten it in a single image.

I personally would have as a separate background image. Then perhaps have the logo and the label on another transparent png and utilise css sprites to re-use them throughout the site. This will halve the number of requests required to download the logo/label, and allow you to optimise each image separately ie the complex background photo, and the more simple logo/label.